# Are any android devices capable of connecting to an AP and another device simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wifi-direct

Since I don't have an Android 4.0 device I haven't been able to test this myself. Also I wonder if connecting device A (a smartphone) to device B (a wifi direct capable device) using Wifi direct would mean that device A would assume it is provided with internet from device B (tethering?). I am trying to make an application for device A that would communicate with a device B that does NOT provide internet, thus it would be interesting to know if such a scenario would lead to device A losing internet connectivity for the duration of the connection. Is the situation different depending on if device A is connected to internet through an AP or through 3G/4G?

Perhaps using Bluetooth would be a solution, but in my case security is an issue, and it seems to me that Wifi direct provides stronger security (WPA2).

Any info would be helpful!

/S

Comment: If you're using wifi, then you're using tcp/ip, aka "internet".

Comment: To quote the wifi direct FAQ (http://www.wi-fi.org/files/20091019_Wi-Fi_Direct_FAQ.pdf)                                                                                                    "How many devices can connect?
A Wi-Fi Direct network can be one-to-one, or one-to-many. The number of devices in a Wi-Fi 
Direct network is expected to be smaller than the number supported by traditional standalone 
access points intended for consumer use."   - has anyone seen this "one-to-many" use?

Comment: Also: "Some Wi-Fi Direct devices will support connections to both an infrastructure network 
and Wi-Fi Direct network at the same time (e.g. a laptop may support an infrastructure 
connection while also belonging to a Wi-Fi Direct network)." Has anyone seen this work?

Comment: Has anyone seen this "one-to-many" use?
Yes, one device acts as a group owner, others are clients of this group.
Has anyone seen this work?
Not with the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: The quote "tcp/ip, aka "internet"" is false. TCP/IP is not Internet, but Internet uses the TCP/IP protocol.

Comment: Wifi direct doesn't interfere with your existing internet connection be it wifi or mobile data. If you are experiencing problems with wifi internet access and want to use mobile data while connected as wifi direct. Just disconnect from all wifi AP and enable "Mobile data always active" option in developer option.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, Wi-Fi Direct doesn't interfere with your connection to the Internet (Wi-Fi or 3G/4G). A problem may be that once your turn on the Wi-Fi (to enable Wi-Fi Direct, your phone will try to connect to one of the saved available networks and will disable your 3G connection. That is because Android (by default) doesn't support dual connection (via both Wi-Fi and 3G/4G), but there is some [applications](http://geeknizer.com/combine-3g-4g-mobile-data-wifi-speed/) around that claim that they can provide such functionality.